# Select rows that end in "Co"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to select only rows that end in "Co," as in Colorado.  I think using a wildcard, like %Co, may be appropriate.

Perhaps a start:

```
 SELECT RIGHT(columnname,2)
```

Comment: "rows that **end** in `Co`, as in `Colorado`"

Comment: `Colorado` doesn't ends with `Co` :P

Comment: Is it a field that needs to end with CO or all fields in a row?

Comment: All Colorado queries end with "Co"

Comment: Aaaaah! CO as in the abbreviation for Colorado state...

Answer (score 5):

To check if the column ends with 'Co' you can use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Table
WHERE  ColumnName LIKE '%Co'
```

Or if you meant "begins with" 'Co':

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    Table
WHERE   ColumnName LIKE 'Co%'
```

Comment: If you're going to downvote, please provide clarity on your reasoning.

Comment: That's not my issue. I posted what the OP asked for. I also posted an alternate solution as he was probably just mistaken in his OP! All good!

Comment: I agree with Mark. don't expect asker to be a world class writer/engineer.

Answer (score 2):

It should be like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE columnname LIKE '%co'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE RIGHT(ColumnName, 2) = 'Co'
```